# Open Source Meme Tracker

Tags: open-source

Is there a open source meme tracker ? I want to create something like techmeme for some specific topic. So is there something in open source that u can use to create ?

Comment: lol... What is the definition of an open source meme tracker anyways? What are its expected functions/capabilities?

Comment: Never heard about 'meme tracker'. Maybe you are creating a completely new kind of software, much like Twitter was when it was launched :-)

Comment: The memetracker module uses algorithms in the machinelearningapi to intelligently filter and group content from designated content sources both internal and external. The module's purpose is to find and display to a community in real time the most interesting conversations and memes within a community as they emerge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Refer to the [Memetracker](https://www.drupal.org/project/memetracker) module. Here is an excerpt from its project page:

> ... uses algorithms in the machinelearningapi to intelligently filter and group content from designated content sources both internal and external. The module's purpose is to find and display to a community in real time the most interesting conversations and memes within a community as they emerge.

Answer (score 0):

Try **[Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/).**

You can use pipes to combine many feeds into one, and you can sort and filter it.
You can also translate it or turn it into a map!

The data recieved is standard RSS, JSON, ...

It's from Yahoo!